# how scala use class or something else defined in java file?

Tags: java, scala

can scala use the class( or something else ) defined in java file? Is it a must to first make these java files to a jar package and then use from scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java from Scala is fairly seamless if you are using [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/).

I minimal example project showing free mixing of Scala and Java could look like:

- project root

  - `build.sbt`
  - `src/`

    - `Hey.java`
    - `There.scala`

**~~ `build.sbt` ~~**

```
javaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")

scalaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")
```

**~~ `src/Hey.java` ~~**

```
public class Hey {
    public static String yay = "Yay!!";
}
```

**~ `src/There.scala`~~**

```
object There extends App {
    println(Hey.yay)
}
```

Then run `There` either by your IDE or by

```
$ sbt 'run-main There'
```

Similarly, if you have a Java library you want to use from your Scala project, you can use it as a Maven dependency without regard for whether it is Scala or Java:

**~~ `build.sbt` ~~**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.neuronrobotics" % "nrjavaserial" % "3.7.5.1", // Java library
    "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.3" // Scala library
)
```

If you are using Maven as your build system, using libraries is as easy as in SBT. Mixing Scala and Java sources is a little trickier using Maven, and requires tapping onto a Maven lifecycle stage before compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing [Owen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007395/3021230) regarding SBT (it's actually easier):

- project root

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - Hey.java
      - scala

        - There.scala

And then:

```
$ sbt run
```